# 502 Bad Gateway error while opening a dockerized react app

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx

I have a multi-container docker app in React that uses Nginx as a server. When I try to open it in the browser I get 502 Bad Gateway error with a message:

```
2021/12/30 11:58:44 [error] 31#31: *31 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.23.0.1, server: , request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.23.0.2:3000/favicon.ico", host: "localhost:3050", referrer: "http://localhost:3050/"
```

Here is nxing config file:

```
upstream client {
  server client:3000;
}

upstream api {
  server api:5000;
}

server {
  listen 80;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://client;
  }

  location /sockjs-node {
    proxy_pass http://client;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
  }

  location /api {
    rewrite /api/(.*) /$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://api;
  }
}
```

Here's the fragment of docker-compose for Nginx:

```
nginx:
    depends_on:
      - api
      - client
    restart: always
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      context: ./nginx
    ports:
      - '3050:80'
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: That error means what it said: Nginx tried to connect to `client:3000` (resolving it to a Docker-internal IP address) and failed.  What is running in the `client` container?  `ports:` don't matter; is the `client` container running an HTTP server listening on `0.0.0.0:3000`?  (What you show in the question seems to be working as intended.)

Comment: Adding EXPOSE 3000 in client's Dockerfile worked, I can access the page

Comment: When I try to post values I get this: ```2021/12/30 15:48:01 [error] 30#30: *20 connect() failed (113: No route to host) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.18.0.1, server: , request: "POST /api/values HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.18.0.3:5000/values", host: "localhost:3050", referrer: "http://localhost:3050/"
``` It seems like it tries to go to '/values' instead of '/api/values'

Comment: I guess it's suppose to because of nginx config, but why does it do that?

Comment: Nevermind, it works now

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for posting this question, it helped me.
Also, in docker-compose.yml file inside the root directory. I had to add **stdin_open: true**,

client:
stdin_open: true
build:
dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
context: ./client
volumes:
- /app/node_modules
- ./client:/app